# Sitecore daily outages

Tags: iis

This is possibly not sitecore related, but since it is a sitecore setup, I'm counting on your expertise

We have a strange event happening on one of our clients website
The website goes down for about an 25 mins every night

- No error's in the sitecore logs at that time
- The worker process is running since we have events in the logs during the outage like the cacheclearer and index job.

IIS logs however show a gap during that time:

```
2016-12-27 02:13:04 10.69.2.5 GET /SomeUrl
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-12-27 02:37:25
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-12-27 02:37:25 10.69.2.5 GET /SomeUrl
```

So my questions are:

- Any Idea what causes IIS to write a log header line in the middle of the log?
- If it is a recycle, they why does Sitecore keep running?

Comment: Just some more info:
- There was no release prior to the nightly downtimes starting

Comment: If it's a timed app pool recycle event - check in the IIS App Pool settings - and assuming overlapped recycling is on, one app pool is "gracefully" shut down while a new one is started; that allows Sitecore to spin down which can take a few minutes (not 25 though).  This is accompanied by a new Sitecore log file and the IIS headers you are showing in your snip above.  If the Sitecore logs roll over at the same time it's definitely a recycle.  The new IIS log header is only written when an actual request is received, which might be rare at 2:30am.

Comment: did you read this forum, it seems IIS restarting the logging process and not restarting the IIS service https://forums.iis.net/t/1181804.aspx?Is+IIS7+5+really+restarting+multiple+times+a+day+on+us+

Comment: Richard, we have only 1 sitecore log file spanning hours before and after the event.
The appool recycle is timed at 8:00, downtime is at 3:05,

Comment: @Balaji, yes I found that thread already, but not much help there.
The strange thing is that if I recycle the website manually, the site is back within 1 or 2 minutes, not the 25min  downtime we observe atm

Comment: Could it be Windows Updates by chance?  2AM hour is usually the  window that Microsoft uses for system updates.

Comment: interesting, we'll check

Comment: Rik did you ever narrow this down to system updates?

Comment: We checked, but system updates are set to manual (we have a patching schedule for our servers), so that was a dead end.

Comment: @Rik are there any CPU/Memory load spikes during that time?

Comment: I actually had the same "header" logged to my IIS logs, so I cross referenced the application logs in the event viewer and found an `APPCRASH` 10 seconds before.  I guess my suggestion would be to review the application logs in the event viewer to see if something else is causing the recycle.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

**Sitecore logs:**

- Do they roll-over at this instant, signifying an application restart?

**IIS Logs**

- IIS Logs - You've left out most of the columns in the log, what does the "time-taken" column show for the one (or several) entries after the delay?
- Is time-taken the same before and after for the same requests, or are they drastically different? If afterwards they're huge then feels like you've got some sort of request locking threads.

Try running a Microsoft Performance Monitor capture during this time looking specifically for:

- ASP.NET Apps / Requests Executing
- ASP.NET Apps / Requests/Sec
- ASP.net v4 / Requests Current
- ASP.net v4 / Requests Queued
- Memory / Pages/sec

This may help show you that requests are coming in but being queued due to saturation or some sort of locking events.

[image]

**Event Viewer**

- Anything in the Application or System event logs at or around this time?